# Unable to retrieve metadata. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation. Entitytype has no key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF code first approach for my project. I have an 'Order' model which has a foreign key 'UserID' of 'ApplicationUser' model as shown below:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public virtual string UserID { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public bool OrderShipped { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Country{ get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to add a new controller with Model class 'Order.cs(MajorProject2.Models)' and Data Context class 'MajorProject2Context (MajorProject2.Models)', it gives an error as given below:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metada for 'MajorProject2.Models.Order'.
>
> One or more validation error were detected during model generation:
>
> IdentityUserLogin::EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined.
>   Define the for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserRole::EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined.
>   Define the for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins:EntityType:EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

How to solve this error?? I've tried different solution from related questions but none of them worked.

Comment: Do you have a DbSet for orders in the context?  public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

Comment: I do have DbSet for orders in the context. But still its not working.

Comment: What is MajorProject2Context ? Is that the same as ApplicationDbContext ? That error is usually related to the Identity models not being properly generated.

Comment: MajorProject2Context is another Dbcontext. I solved the error by creating single DbContext instead of using two DbContexts.

Answer (score 0):

I had two DbContext: MajorProject2Context and ApplicationDbContext. I got that error since I had foreign key from ApplicationDbContext in one of the model in MajorProjectContext. The only solution I found was to merge two DbContexts into a single DbContext(ApplicationDbContext). I had to make few changes but everything works fine now.

Comment: That's one way to reuse identity models in your app context. The other is to make a copy of the applicationuser class in your second context and add a DbSet<ApplicationUser>.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add an ID to your class order. You see, EF generates the table with your filds. And it requires the field named ID. 
So change `OrderID` to `ID` and everything have to be allright.